# Is there any way to return data from gremlin in the form of hashmap?

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph

I want to know whether I can get data from Gremlin query in the form of HashMap(One vertex as key and another as value).

`g.V().has('familyName','Smith').as('familyName').out().as('name').select('familyName','name').by('property1').by('property2')`

The above queries retrieves the result as :

```
{
'familyName:Smith'
'name:John'
}
```

I want the result to be

```
{
'Smith:John'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When the keys of the `Map` you want to produce must be dynamically determined then you typically use `group()`.

```
g.V().has('familyName','Smith').
  group().
    by('familyName').
    by(out().values('name'))
```